# How to recognise Webix objects using UFT?

Tags: object, automation, qtp, webix

Is there any way to recognise **Webix objects** (where Webix is a JavaScript and HTML5 framework for developing cross platform HTML5 and CSS3 compatible applications)using UFT? 
I have an application **web based** but I am not able to recognise its objects when I checked the page source then it is showing me that all the objects on the page are **Webix** based.
So I want to know is there any possibility to recognise these objects using UFT or is there any plugin or patch available to resolve this issue?
My UFT version is 12.02

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update UFT version in your question

Comment: Did a quick check with the demo page `http://webix.com/demo/charts/scales/` UFT 12.X is recognizing the objects. Try recording a script only with Web, ActiveX add-on enable. Also add the HTML source after scrubbing important data that will give us some idea of how the web page is...